# hector_localization build error

Tags: ros, hector-localization, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

trying to catkin_make the hector_localization package in ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 I get the following errors:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package geographic_msgs.

  Set geographic_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for geographic_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    geographic_msgsConfig.cmake
    geographic_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation_core/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:               RelWithDebInfo
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:        -O3 -DNDEBUG
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO: -O3 -g -DNDEBUG
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:     -Os -DNDEBUG
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:          -g
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_pose_estimation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /home/tinytron/catkin_ws/devel/share/hector_pose_estimation_core/cmake/hector_pose_estimation_coreConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findgeographic_msgs.cmake or a configuration file for
  package geographic_msgs.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findgeographic_msgs.cmake or set
  geographic_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for geographic_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    geographic_msgsConfig.cmake
    geographic_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198652/hector_localization-build-error/) by [tinytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/20467/tinytron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-12-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-12-01**:
Do you have all dependencies installed? Especially "geographic_msgs"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, what solved the problem was manually installing two packages from git.

Namely **geographic_msgs** and **uuid_msgs**.

I'm not quite sure why those went missing but now hector_localization compiled.

Thanks Dirk!

---

Originally posted by [tinytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/20467/tinytron/) with karma: 45 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The_Mad_Geometer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23167/the_mad_geometer/) on 2015-08-27**:
I am completely new to the structure of GitHub and of repositories, in general.  Which commands did you use to install the geographic_msgs and uuid_msgs?

Thanks!